# FireFox:In a contentEditable div, why can't a select element get focus?

Tags: html, contenteditable

Below is my code. My problem is that the select element can't get focus, so I can't use it to select an option.

```
<div id='editpanel' class="editpanel" contentEditable='true' >
  <select>
     <option value ='volvo'>Volvo</option>
     <option value ='saab'>Saab</option>
     <option value='opel'>Opel</option>
     <option value='audi'>Audi</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

What can I do to change this select element so it gets focus? I already tried setting tabindex=-1. If I add contentEditable=false on the select element, it gets focus, but can't be deleted.

othere element like  set contentEditable ,they still can be deleted,except the  element.

Tested in Firefox 8.
I tried another way ,I make a div surround the selection like :

```
<div><select contentEditable='false'>...</select></div>
```

It can be set focus,and can be deleted,but the div made the a break of current row.

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: @mididelux: that 's different

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kfRSW/ it works.

Comment: That's a bug in Firefox. I don't remember its number right now but I think that it was introduced with Firefox 2 or 3

Comment: tks,but any package of firefox to fix that bug?

Comment: No,robert ,it doesn't work in Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

When you have form elements such as [select] inside a contentEditable div, it will inherit the setting and will not allow user interaction with the element. Simply set [select contentEditable='false'] and you will be able to interact with the dropdown without a problem.